# Issue faced while downloading NKIssue - Newsstand App

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

I am developing a Newsstand App in iOS. When I work around with the developed application on simulator, everything seems fine. But when I installed the app on device and worked, sometimes downloading of NKIssue seems not working, especially when the app goes to background while downloading. I am displaying the percentage of downloads. So when the app goes to background and again back to foreground, the percentage of downloading is not updating. That means downloading is not happening.

The problem that I doubt is network availability. In the mac machine I am using high speed net connectivity, so that everything seems fine, especially the downloading of NKIssue. But on device, the connection is very slow. So I tried sharing the internet from mac through wifi and then I used that wifi on my device. After that everything seems fine on device too. Background downloading of NKIssue too seems fine. So strongly I doubt that the issue is with the bandwidth of net connectivity.

Even though I would like to know how to handle the background downloading of NKIssue on low bandwidth internet connectivity. Can anybody give me some suggestion to solve this issue. Also one thing I would like to let you know, when I downloaded another newsstand app for reference, it asked me to use wifi for downloading of NKIssue. So is it mandatory to restrict downloading of NKIssue using wifi or high speed network only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Newsstand background download happens only when the device is on Wi-Fi network